# How do I get started with (MuleSoft) Mule ESB

Tags: mule, esb

Are there any good resources to get started with Mule ESB? Any good tutorials, blogs or books?

Of course, I have visited its official website http://www.mulesoft.org/ which is definitely a good starting point; however, there is always more that we can learn.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The following is how I got myself started, and I find it really effective.

**First, explore the features of Mule ESB with:**

- MuleSoft Official Documentation @
  http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Basic+Studio+Tutorial
- Mule ESB Cookbook @
  [http://www.amazon.com/Mule-ESB-Cookbook-Zakir-Laliwala-ebook/dp/B00EQ67J44](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EQ67J44)

**Then, learn the core concepts of Mule with:**

- Mule in Action, Second Edition, book from http://www.manning.com/dossot2/
- Understand the code samples from https://github.com/ddossot/mule-in-action-2e

**Finally, you're definitely interested to know what are some of the latest trends & techniques for doing your tasks:**

- Follow Stackoverflow with Mule tag @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule
- Attend MuleSoft Summit & Conference (*I haven't attended one myself; however, my friends who did last year seem to have benefited from it. They shared new techniques with me. I'm going for one tomorrow though. I'll share more here if necessary.)

P.S. If you wonder why am I writing all these, I'm doing all these because I benefited greatly from a similar Node.js post when I'm starting with Node. It's called "How do I get started with Node.js" at Stackoverflow.

Please add more to this thread if you know of any good blogs, screen casts and etc... Cheers :)